# How to create a query with order by deeply nested jsonb data?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `availability` with 4 columns: `productcode`, `currency`, `bookableitems`, `summary`.

`bookableitems` is JSONB.

I need to select all records with `currency = 'USD'` and `productOptionCode = 'TG11'` and `ORDER BY [recommendedRetailPrice of ageBand = 'CHILD'] DESC`.

Selection by `currency` and `productOptionCode` is easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM availability
WHERE currency = 'USD' AND bookableitems @> '[{"productOptionCode": "TG11"}]'
```

but I can not find example how to order by so deep data (especially how to do 4 nested loops, for `bookableitems`, `seasons`, `pricingRecords` and `pricingDetails` in order to find `ageBand = 'CHILD'`).

Example of one row:

```
"productcode": "46258P1", 
"currency": "USD", 
"bookableitems": [
    {
        "seasons": [
            {
                "startDate": "2019-08-12",
                "pricingRecords": [
                    {
                        "daysOfWeek": ["MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY", "SUNDAY"],
                        "timedEntries": [{"startTime": "20:30"}], 
                        "pricingDetails": [
                            {
                                "price": {
                                    "original": {
                                        "bookingFee": 8.69,
                                        "partnerNetPrice": 115.87,
                                        "partnerTotalPrice": 124.56,
                                        "recommendedRetailPrice": 139.49
                                    }
                                }, 

                                "ageBand": "CHILD",
                                "minTravelers": 1,
                                "pricingPackageType": "PER_PERSON"
                            },
                            
                            {
                                "price": {
                                    "original": {
                                        "bookingFee": 11.57,
                                        "partnerNetPrice": 154.21,
                                        "partnerTotalPrice": 165.78,
                                        "recommendedRetailPrice": 185.65
                                    }
                                }, 

                                "ageBand": "ADULT",
                                "minTravelers": 1,
                                "pricingPackageType": "PER_PERSON"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],

        "productOptionCode": "TG11"
    },

    {
        "seasons": [
            {
                "startDate": "2019-08-12",
                "pricingRecords": [
                    {
                        "daysOfWeek": ["MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY", "SUNDAY"],
                        "timedEntries": [{"startTime": "20:30"}],
                        "pricingDetails": [
                            {
                                "price": {
                                    "original": {
                                        "bookingFee": 0.0, 
                                        "partnerNetPrice": 0.0, 
                                        "partnerTotalPrice": 0.0, 
                                        "recommendedRetailPrice": 0.0
                                    }
                                }, 

                                "ageBand": "INFANT", 
                                "minTravelers": 1, 
                                "pricingPackageType": "PER_PERSON"
                            },

                            {
                                "price": {
                                    "original": {
                                        "bookingFee": 8.95, 
                                        "partnerNetPrice": 119.28, 
                                        "partnerTotalPrice": 128.23, 
                                        "recommendedRetailPrice": 143.59
                                    }
                                },

                                "ageBand": "ADULT",
                                "minTravelers": 1,
                                "pricingPackageType": "PER_PERSON"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ], 

        "productOptionCode": "TG1"
    }
], 

"summary": {"fromPrice": 185.65}
```

Postgresql v13.

Could anyone please show me correct query?

Comment: your example data is malformatted for JSON (so we can't readily test anything without a lot of work).  You must use double quotes, not single, in JSON.

Comment: Also, you have many single-element arrays in your example.  If they are always single-element, then why do they exist?  If they are not always single-element, then we don't know what they might look like in a more full example, so it is poor example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT *, jsonb_path_query(a.bookableitems, '$[*].seasons[*].pricingRecords[*].pricingDetails[*] ? (@.ageBand == "CHILD")') -> 'price' -> 'original' -> 'recommendedRetailPrice' AS retailPrice
FROM availability as a
WHERE currency = 'USD' AND bookableitems @> '[{"productOptionCode": "TG11"}]'
ORDER BY retailPrice DESC;
```

This request `jsonb_path_query(a.bookableitems, '$[*].seasons[*].pricingRecords[*].pricingDetails[*] ? (@.ageBand == "CHILD")')` returns this object:

```
{
    "price": {
        "original": {
            "bookingFee": 8.69,
            "partnerNetPrice": 115.87,
            "partnerTotalPrice": 124.56,
            "recommendedRetailPrice": 139.49
        }
    }, 

    "ageBand": "CHILD",
    "minTravelers": 1,
    "pricingPackageType": "PER_PERSON"
}
```

and then `-> 'price' -> 'original' -> 'recommendedRetailPrice' AS retailPrice` simply extracts `recommendedRetailPrice` as `retailPrice` to use in `ORDER BY` part.

If somebody needs to check if "CHILD" exists, just add:

```
AND jsonb_path_exists(a.bookableitems, '$[*].seasons[*].pricingRecords[*].pricingDetails[*] ? (@.ageBand == "CHILD")')
```

inside WHERE part.

[This Postgresql docs page helped](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html) and [this article](https://habr.com/ru/company/postgrespro/blog/500440/).

Answer (score 0):

No PostgreSQL index will simultaneously directly satisfy all of those requirements when operating on that data, unless we assume 'TG11' is hardcoded and not a changeable parameter (which seems rather unlikely).